# How to make all the error responses for API access in Content-Type of application/json instead of Content-Type of text/html in Flask?

Tags: flask

I am building a Flask app that support access by human users and through API. The `/api` path and its subpaths are dedicated for API access. All API access should receive a response in JSON, i.e., with `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

I have organized all API endpoints within a blueprint named `api`. Using the technique illustrated in [Implementing API Exceptions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/apierrors/), I have defined a custom error class called `ApiAccessError` and registered the handler for it in the `api` blueprint, so whenever `ApiAccessError` is raised in a view function in the `api` blueprint, the registered handler for `ApiAccessError` is invoked to generate a JSON response with `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

The issue I have with the current design is that whenever an error that is not an `ApiAccessError` is raised in handling an API request, the response to the request is not in JSON but in HTML, i.e. having `Content-Type` of `text/html`. Such an error can occur, for example, in accessing a GET-only API endpoint with the POST method. In this case, the server response is in HTML with status code of 405. I would like the response to be in JSON while keeping the status code of 405. How can set Flask to respond to the 405 error and all other default errors in JSON instead of HTML in handling API requests?

Comment: Try implementing a global error handler with the instructions from the page you linked, and using the flask request global with a check like request.path.startswith('/api') to decide to override the content-type or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further examination of the error handling mechanism through [Application Errors](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/), [Error Handlers](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/blueprints/#error-handlers), [Custom Error Pages](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/), the source code, and @Jonhasacat's suggestion. I think the best way to accomplish what I wanted in the program is to register an error handler at the app level for `HTTPException`. In my application, this is done as:

```
def handle_http_exception(e: HTTPException):
    if request.path.startswith(API_PATH):
        # Start with the response represented by the error
        resp = e.get_response()

        # jsonify the response
        resp.set_data(
            json.dumps(
                {
                    'name': e.name,
                    'err_msg': e.description
                }
            )
        )
        resp.content_type = 'application/json'

        return resp
    else:
        return e

app.register_error_handler(HTTPException, handle_http_exception)
```

This works because, roughly speaking, all errors raised in the process of handling a request that is an instance of `Exception` is either an `HTTPException` or an error to be converted to `HTTPException` if it doesn't have a handler registered for handling it.